# PHP/Python json_decode doesn´t display special characters like €

Tags: php, json, utf-8, special-characters, decoding

I got a json which is generated in a python program and looks like this:

```
{"0": {"ausschreiber": "Beispiel; Zeitarbeit GmbH", "beschreibung": "\r\nF\u00fcr unseren Kunden suchen wir motivierte studentische Aushilfen auf flexibler Stundenbasis (450\u0080-Basis)", "datum": "17.11.2016", "name": "Studentische Hilfskr\u00e4fte gesucht", "email": "info@hindi.de"}}
```

now i am decoding the json in my php program to get an associative array and display this on the website.
The Problem is that the special characters like the € char are not displayed but special chars like ö ä ü are displayed.
Here is the php program:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

function compare($old_data, $new_data){
    $old_result = json_decode($old_data, true);
    $new_result = json_decode($new_data, true);
    echo $new_result[0]['beschreibung'];
}

function go4it(){
    $db_data=json_content(); //creates the json from the Database
    $crawler_data = file_get_contents('http://localhost/phppath/python_program.cgi'); //calls the cgi which returns the json
    compare($db_data, $crawler_data);
}
go4it();
```

What i tried:

- set the header to utf-8
- `$new_result = json_decode(utf8_encode($new data), true);`
- `iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", "UTF-8");`
- `iconv_set_encoding("input_encoding", "UTF-8");`
- `iconv_set_encoding("output_encoding", "UTF-8");`

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT 1**
so it seems like the issue is located in the python program, thanks to @FranzGleichmann . I think the problem is with the encoding of the page where i get the content from. The page says it is ISO-8859-1 so i tried this:

```
url = 'https://www.example.com'
source_code = requests.get(url)
plain_text = source_code.text
plain_text.decode('iso-8859-1', 'ignore').encode('utf8', 'ignore')
print(plain_text.encoding)
```

but then i get the error: "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in position 8496: ordinal not in range(128)"

Comment: JSON that you posted is invalid

Comment: your generating script seems to have used some wrong charset or whatever. it escaled € as `\u0080` - it should have been `\u20ac` instead.

Comment: @Nordenheim now it is valid, isn´t it? the json is way longer so i shortened it.

Comment: @JeremyHarris i thought JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE is just for encoding but i am decoding the json

Comment: @FranzGleichmann yeah my python program generates this output, so the issue is there?

Comment: @Jobeso probably. my `var_dump(json_encode("€"))` returned `string '"\u20ac"' (length=8)`, which makes me guess that your python script makes an error while encoding.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann ok then i´ll post the python code, too

Comment: @FranzGleichmann now i edited some information to the question. Do you have any suggestions for a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a problem with the python script